# MVC 3 VirtualPathUtility Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 app with a Configuration folder that holds XML files specific to my application.  I'm trying to enumerate the files in a view like this:

```
string configPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Configuration");
foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(configPath, "*.xml"))
{
  // ...
}
```

However, the path resolves to C:\Configuration as evidenced by the error message:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Configuration\'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know but this should work in your controller:

```
string configPath = Server.MapPath("~/Configuration");
```